# unable to fetch records from multiple tables using join

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii framework. i am wonder how i can get records from multiple tables i did research but couldn't find any usefull link i am using following code for this please let me know where i am missing

my model Task.php

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'prj_user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'id'),
    );
}
```

model User.php

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        array('task', self::HAS_MANY, 'Task','project_id')
    );
}
```

and this is my main controller

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('t.id', 1);
$criteria->with = array( 'prj_user' => array('select' => 'username,title,roles', 'joinType'=>'inner join'));

$rows = Task::model()->findAll( $criteria );
```

but still i am getting columns only from task table but i need more three columns from users table please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Let Yii worry about joining your tables. Your relations looks fine so you should be able to access them directly*

For example, what does this return?

```
foreach ($rows as $task)
{
    if ( isset($task->prj_user) )
        echo $task->prj_user->username . "<br>";
}
```

Or this?

```
this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>new CActiveDataProvider('Task'),
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'prj_user.username',
        'prj_user.title',
        'prj_user.roles',
    )
));
```

->with() is used for eager loading, so at this point you probably don't need it. In fact, unless I misread you completely, you can remove your criteria all together.

Comment: but i want to want to get a single row where contains fields of both tabls